# Import password protected excel file data into MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I have a process to import user data from an excel file to MySQL DB. Everything working fine but the problem I'm facing is the user-data excel file is uploaded by various users and some of which are password protected. I want to know is there any way to unlock a password-protected Excel file programmatically and import the data in it.
Note: I have the passwords of the respective files.
Please help.

Comment: You can try msoffcrypto-tool is a Python tool and library for decrypting encrypted MS Office files with a password. And use PhpSpreadsheet to read the unencrypted file in a temporary folder.
I used it in some projects, work great.

Comment: Hi @SimoneRossaini,  thanks for the response. I have ZERO knowledge in Python( I know it sucks not knowing the wonderful language). So I don't really know how to use your solution in real life.

Comment: If you somehow tell me if I can implement this above tool in my PHP server then it'll be a big help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start [here](https://github.com/nolze/msoffcrypto-tool)